# Ember Store findRecord (if called with same parameters on the same page) resolve only once

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have the following code in my component:

```
hotelObserver: Ember.computed(function(){
    this.get("store").findRecord("hotel", "hotel1").then((hotel)=>{
        this.set("hotel", hotel);
    });
})
```

In reality when 2 components are rendered on the same page, only the first promise is resolved. The second promise's then is never called. So I figured that the problem only surfaces when findRecord is called 2 ore more times with the same parameters. Is this the bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: `hotelObserver` this property looks like observer, but you are using computed. and also in your computed property which is not returning value. one more thing computed property is not promise aware.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this call in the `init` hook of the component, or in the `didReceiveAttributes`, depending on wether you want to fetch the data on init / on attributes update.

Or, better, why not fetching the data in the `model` hook of a route ? And passing the data around as a component's argument ?